# Exporting ifc file from revit file in Forge using specific settings

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, revit, ifc

Looking up online I only found a way to export a Revit file to IFC using the settings inside the Revit File already.

Is there a way to export an ifc file from a Revit model using a specific settings (not the settings inside the Revit model)?
(For example, exporting to IFC4 with 1st level boundaries)

Inside a Revit file there is an option to export settings and then load them.

Is there a way to use this settings file automatically on a different Revit file that does not contain this settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the export you refer to is built in to the Forge translation system, cf. [Supported Translation Formats](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations).

In that case, I do not believe that you can modify the standard settings.

However, you could achieve what you want using the [Forge Design Automation API](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page) for Revit instead.

In that case, you could implement a .NET Revit add-in that applies the required settings and launches the export.

That add-in can then be re-packaged for use in the Design Automation API framework, for real-time online web access.

Here is an example add-in [IfcSpaceZoneBoundaries](https://github.com/jeremytammik/IfcSpaceZoneBoundaries) that I created to retrieve IFC spaces and zones and their boundaries.

For more info, please refer to [Design Automation API for Revit or DA4R](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.55).